# javascript : Return selected row of values from Bootstrap Modal table list to parent web page

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-modal

I am new bootstrap modal and javascript and need help to resolve this

Desired Outcome:

1.Parent screen open modal window find username

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManagerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <button type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#findByName"
                    id="findManagerDetails">
                Find
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal" id="findByName" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("../Admin/Find");
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="validationSummary" class="validation-summary">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

```
 $("#findManagerDetails").click(function () {
        type = "Manager";
        var searchName = $("#ManagerName").val();
        console.log(searchName);
        document.getElementById("Search").value = searchName;
        document.getElementById("SearchBtn").click();
    });
```

2.Modal Dialog show list of userid of result from searched username

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#clear").click(function () {
            document.getElementById("Search").value = "";
            var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
            SetData.html("");
        });
        $("#SearchBtn").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
            var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
            SetData.html("");
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/")Admin/GetByIFName?name=" + SearchValue,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $("#DataSearching").empty();
                    if (result.length == 0) {
                        SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match Data</td></tr>')
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            //based on result row number index return value to respective controls and close modal window
                            //data incorrect
                            var Data = "<tr>" +                                   
                                "<td><a href=?id=" + value.UserID + "# onclick='SetName();'>" + value.UserID + "</a></td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.UserName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.Email + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";
                            
                            SetData.append(Data);

                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

3.Select one of the rows in Modal dialog return selected userid, username and email back to parent screen

```
function SetName() {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        userid = urlParams.get('id');

        console.log("id=" + userid);

        if (type == "Manager") {
            document.getElementById("ManagerID").value = userid;
            document.getElementById("btnValidateManagerID").click();
        }

        if (type == "Interviewer") {
            document.getElementById("InterviewerID").value = userid;
            document.getElementById("btnValidateInterviewerID").click();
        }

        if (type == "Interviewer1") {
            document.getElementById("Interviewer1ID").value = userid;
            document.getElementById("btnValidateInterviewer1ID").click();
        }

        $("#findByName").modal("hide");
    }
```

Question: How do I get from point 2 to 3?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

credits:https://forums.asp.net/t/2142972.aspx?ASP+NET+MVC+5+Getting+Table+row+data+when+click+after+it+has+been+populated+by+Ajax+Json

Below is the correct code for passing the data from modal dialog json clicked row back to parent screen controls which answer point 3.

```
<script>      
    $(document).on('click', '#DataSearching tr', function () {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        //alert("Your data is: " + type + " , " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[1]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[2]));
        if (type == "Manager") {
            document.getElementById("ManagerID").value = $.trim(tableData[0]);
            document.getElementById("ManagerName").value = $.trim(tableData[1]);
            document.getElementById("ManagerEmailAddress").value = $.trim(tableData[2]);
        }
        
        $("#findByName").modal("hide");
    });

</script>
```